# Acquiring the class object of the class which was annotated with @ContextConfiguration?

Tags: unit-testing, spring

This problem isn't a showstopper, but I've been wondering if it is possible to acquire the class object of the class (the test class) which was annotated with @ContextConfiguration("mycontext.xml") from a bean's code defined in mycontext.xml?

The motive:

In my current project I keep quite a few test spring contexts, which have become more and more similar to eachother over the months (so instead of fine-tuning each, I've started just pulling in everything lazily). It has come to a point where they mostly differ only in the database initialization script(s) they run with  (if they differ at all to begin with). 
So I was thinking of a neat way of getting rid of all the context xmls which contain nothing but an import and and an init-db tag.

The solution I'm primarily looking for:

Annotate the unit test classes with an annotation which somehow sets the paths to the db init scripts I'd like to run for the test cases. Injecting property-placeholder value(s) would more or less do it, but it would be nice to be able to run 1..n db scripts.

I recon that with BeanFactoryPostProcessors and BeanPostProcessors a lot can be achieved, but for starters, how do I acquire the magic annotation I put on my test class?

I hope this post makes some sense, any input is welcome :)

Comment: I you use JUnit, then there is an other Pitfall that you mayby not have considered yet. Junit create an NEW instance of the test class for EACH test case!

Answer (score 0):

I you use JUnit, then there is an other Pitfall that you mayby not have considered yet. Junit create an NEW instance of the test class for EACH test case!

I have the feeling that you try do do the whole stuff in the wrong way, or lets say a to complicated one.

Why not have a small spring configuration fill for each db script that include the core spring configuration and also reference the db init script.
Then you can use the `@ContextConfiguration` for that specific configuration.

Example

junit test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/config1.xml")
public class MyTest {...}
```

config1.xml

```
...
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" />
<bean class="MyDbScript">
   <property name="file" value"classpath:/SCRIPTS/config1.sql" />
</bean>
...
```

---

An other solution would be not automatically setup the database on startup, but after an invocation.
I am not 100% sure if its work, because I do not know if `@Before` annotated test methods run before or after Spring has injected the beans in the test case.

Assume you have a bean of class `HandTriggeredDbScriptExecutor` that has a method `run` which takes the script to run:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class MyTest {

    @Autowire
    HandTriggeredDbScriptExecutor handTriggeredDbScriptExecutor;

    @Before
    public void setUpDb() {
       this.handTriggeredDbScriptExecutor.run("classpath:/SCRIPTS/config1.sql");
    }        
}
```